# Drop Row At Numeric Index - SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, uitableview, titanium

I am attempting this in the JavaScript language using the Titanium IDE.

What I'm doing is populating a table from an SQL database, and then allowing you to delete rows in this table. So, when the user chooses to delete a row in the table, I will get it's index in the table (ex. row 5), and then pass this to the SQL and drop the row at the index (so, row 5).

Did some research and couldn't find any decent sources on this, and so I essentially need a way of dropping the SQL table row based on the numeric index of the row the user selects.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not really how SQL databases work. Rows do not have inherent ordering. You should delete rows by specifying their primary key value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL table should have an unique id for each row. So when user select row on your table, you have to match it with that unique id and then just remove that unique id from database.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling it was going to come to this. This is currently what I have, and I was just looking to find if there is that possibility to do it like I mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: `DELETE FROM Table OFFSET <row_number>` Or `ROW_NUMBER()` but you should not do that